# SSD Upgrade and Clone Blackscreen

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd

Trying to upgrade and replace my HDD with an SSD. The HDD is 250Gb (100Gb Used) and I cloned it to a 120Gb SSD with Macrium Reflect free (Windows 10). Disconnected the HDD and plugged the SSD into the SATA port and booted. Black screen after windows logo. It disappears and a loading icon appears shortly and then black screen. No error message.

Safe mode does not work, neither does repair (local or from Win 10 USB stick).

In DOS I see I am on X:\ but I do have C:\ and D:\ and I can change to them and see my files. I didn't have a C: and D: before (just C:) so that's weird.

In diskpart I see 2 volumes both NTFS and "healthy" and of type Partition (not boot).

How can I recover?

UPDATE:
bootrec /scanos -> Finds no OS on the SSD
bootrec /fixboot -> access denied

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions posted on these other questions? https://superuser.com/questions/862990/os-does-not-boot-after-cloning-from-hdd-to-ssd?rq=1 https://superuser.com/questions/706507/cloning-hdd-to-ssd-but-windows-fails-to-boot?rq=1 https://superuser.com/questions/1093305/windows-10-fails-to-boot-after-hdd-clone-to-ssd?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to redo the whole process - second time around it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I am not with Macrium Reflect, what I think is using system image backup.

Create your system image and restore it from WinPE, since you have an USB stick, thing will be easy.

After all, Microsoft’s own tool is safe to use.

How to make a full backup of your Windows 10 PC

https://www.windowscentral.com/how-make-full-backup-windows-10